# All exe's getting vlc exe's on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

Am facing quite strange problem.Am on windows7 and whenever i install vlc player on my system all other exe's are getting converted into vlc exe and only after uninstalling vlc they get into their real shape...
                                    What could be the problem??